# I got the following error while running gem install mysql2 on windows 10

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I downloaded and installed ruby from this https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ -> Ruby+Devkit 2.7.3-1 (x64) and follow the installation steps. but I got a error when I tried to install mysql2 for rails using

```
gem install mysql2
```

ruby version is 2.7.3p183

rails version is 6.1.3.2

gem version is 3.1.6

> ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
> The last version of mysql2 (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 0.5.3. Try installing it with `gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.3`
> mysql2 requires Ruby version >= 2.2, < 2.7.dev. The current ruby version is 2.7.3.183.

I tried gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.3 but got same error.

I installed mysql before running this command, and I also have mysql on XAMPP.
I installed MYSQL using mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.25.0

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting this error as 0.5.3 is the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled my current ruby and reinstalled with rubyinstaller-devkit-2.6.7-1-x64.exe and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'd move to linux ubuntu or Mac for dev you'll get a lot more support and workarounds if needed. For ruby support on windows is non-existent. Not all gems work.